# dc.js average value per sku not correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm making a stacked average barchart using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js, which is based on d3 and crossfilter. I am new in dc.js library..i have display the row chart,pie chart and data table.Initially when data is loaded all the stacked barchart average value display correctly.when i'm click the row chart of one value the average value of stacked barchart can't Display properly.  I can't understand how to create a stacked barchart following the csv format.

```
 Sku      Stars partner review  Date
 KBU12     5       Amazon   Preferred over the r.   02/05/2016
 KBU12     5       Amazon   Gorgeous fixture    05/06/2016
 KBU12     2       Amazon   Awesome value!  02/02/2016
 KBU12      2      Homedepot    Kitchen Remodel 06/09/2016
 KPF1650    3   Homedepot   Wow 02/08/2016
 KPF1650    4   Homedepot   Sharp!  05/04/2015
 KPF1650    5   Homedepot   cool design 05/05/2015
 KPF1650    1   Amazon  Beautiful   09/08/2015
 KPF1650    2   Amazon  Very happy  09/11/2016
 GV-100     3   Amazon  Great quality   12/12/2015
 GV-100     5   Homedepot   Love it 01/03/2015
 GV-100     1   Homedepot   Sad I had to return it  12/10/2014
 GV-100     4   Homedepot   Beautiful But Stiff 12/11/2014
 GV-100     2   Homedepot   Kitchen Faucet  10/04/2014
 KBU24      3   Build       I like the look of faucet   04/05/2014
 KBU24      5   Build       Commercial style without    06/07/2016
 KBU24      4   Build       Very Cool   06/07/2014
 KBU24      1   Build       Excellent!  01/04/2014
 KBU24      3   Build       A beautiful Vessel Sink 07/06/2013
 KBU24      5   Amazon      Beautiful addition  05/04/2013
```

Comment: Can you add some example code in for example jsfiddle to make it easier to help you

Comment: Here's a template fiddle that you can start with. It includes dc.js and its dependencies: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/jusjkm8j/

Comment: @EthanJewett  i have updated all the code in jsfiddle.

Comment: i have display stars average values in barchart named as 'Review by partners' .when i have click in year pie chart, month chart or sku row chart  that time average value is not properly display. attached fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jusjkm8j/27/

Comment: It looks to me like the value in "Review by partners" is correct in this fiddle when we filter by year. Could you describe specifically what you are seeing that is wrong? It would be best to update your question with this information and the example.

Comment: @EthanJewett now i have update the code. https://jsfiddle.net/pramod24/jusjkm8j/33/

Comment: So, it worked before and it doesn't work now? What changed?

Comment: i have changed the function reduce.group function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a little while to figure out what you were asking, because there is no stacked bar chart here.

But I saw that the "Review by Partners" chart was empty, and it uses averages, so I think this is what you're asking about.

It looks like the parsing of Stars is incorrect:

```
 d.Stars = d.Stars.match(/\d+/);
```

[String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array of strings. So reduceAdd can't work with this directly when it tries to sum:

```
p.total += v.Stars;
```

Try pulling the first result and converting it to an integer:

```
d.Stars = +d.Stars.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Working (I think) fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5xc9rh4f/1/

Comment: Gordon how to display month in squence wise  in barchart like.jan,feb,mar   i have attached fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5xc9rh4f/1/

Comment: Hi @santosh, could you please open another question for that? Basically you will need to use a time or number scale for x, instead of ordinal - ordinal will sort alphabetically.

Comment: i have open question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998942/how-to-display-month-in-squence-wise-in-dc-js